# "Error encountered during SQL installation"

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-registry, chocolatey

During my internship at a company that utilizes Sage software, I faced challenges while attempting to install Microsoft SQL Server, which is required for Sage. I encountered multiple errors during the installation process, preventing me from successfully installing SQL Server. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to resolve these errors on my own. I am seeking assistance to overcome these installation issues and successfully install SQL Server for Sage software.

```
The installation of the "Database Engine Services" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, preventing the setup process from completing.
The installation of the "SQL Server Replication" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, causing the setup process to fail.
The installation of the "SQL Browser" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, resulting in the setup process failure.
The installation of the "SQL Writer" feature encountered an unexpected error with the SQL Server Writer Component, producing an error code 2718. 
The installation of the "Client Tools Backwards Compatibility" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, leading to the setup process failure.
The installation of the "Client Tools SDK" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, causing the setup process to fail.
The installation of the "Client Tools Connectivity" feature failed due to an error with a dependency, resulting in the setup process failure.
The installation of the "Setup Support Files" feature encountered an error during the setup process.
```

I am seeking assistance in resolving these errors to successfully install SQL Server for Sage software.

I uninstalled SQL and deleted all instances of SQL from my PC including my registry editor, I searched for all keys and values containing SQL and I deleted them. I tried installing again, but I keep getting the same error. I deleted them again. then I tried installing with Chocolatey hoping it will install but it didn't, it gave me the error: - SQL-server-2019 (exited -2061893606) - Error while running

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server? Enterprise or Standard? Go and find the log file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log` and the details should show you what pre-requisite is missing.

Comment: The edition is express

Comment: Check if it's compatible with the OS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/use-sql-server-in-windows

Comment: Are you aware of the limitations of using SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: it is compatible with the OS

Comment: there is not detail pointing which pre-requisite is missing

Comment: no i am not aware of the limitations, pls can you tell me

Comment: I have resolved hundreds of these issues, check the logs as said in the first comment. There is a summary and a detailed log. The answer will be in there. If you can't find the issue, upload the logs for us to look.